# Salesforce Bulk API and Apache Camel Salesforce Component

Tags: java, rest, salesforce, apache-camel

I have to integrate my project with salesforce. More specifically, I need to be able to bulk-import some salesforce.com data into our system, Accounts for example. I've done enough R&D to conclude that SF Bulk API is the way to go. Our project is a Java system, and we are already using Camel which happens to have a Salesforce component that seems to work quite nicely.

This question is as much about Salesforce as it is about Camel.

The nature of SF bulk api is they are asynchronous. That means, that I submit a job, then I have to poll for status, and then the status becomes COMPLETED at some point and then I can pull the results. So far so good, but what I need to understand is how, from Camel standpoint, I can initiate this polling after I submit my job ? As you can see in my example I am using a delayer, but that is suboptimal -- some batches may take hours to be ready.

Furthermore, as you can see I am holding on to jobInfo variable. That is because it does not seem to be passed by getQueryResultIds. Is there any way in camel to preserve some parts of the exchange as it gets pushed down the pipeline ?

Here is the code I've written to bulk-import accounts (I took some proprietary pieces out):

```
final BatchInfo[] bi = new BatchInfo[1];
from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&delay=10")
.process(new Processor() {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
    {
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo();
        jobInfo.setContentType(ContentType.CSV);
        jobInfo.setOperation(OperationEnum.QUERY);
        jobInfo.setObject("Account");
        jobInfo.setConcurrencyMode(ConcurrencyModeEnum.PARALLEL);
        exchange.getOut().setBody(jobInfo);
    }

})
.to("salesforce:createJob")
.to("salesforce:createBatchQuery?sObjectQuery=select Id,Name,Type,BillingCity,BillingState," +
        "BillingPostalCode,BillingCountry,Phone from Account")
.delay(10000)
.to("salesforce:getBatch")
.process(new Processor() {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
    {
        BatchInfo batchInfo = exchange.getIn().getBody(BatchInfo.class);
        bi[0] = batchInfo;
        exchange.getOut().setBody(batchInfo);

    }

})
.to("salesforce:getQueryResultIds")
.process(new Processor() {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
    {
        if (exchange.getException() != null)
        {
            exchange.getException().printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
        Collection resultIds = exchange.getIn().getBody(Collection.class);
        String resultId = (String) resultIds.iterator().next();
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(SalesforceEndpointConfig.RESULT_ID, resultId);
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(SalesforceEndpointConfig.JOB_ID, bi[0].getJobId());
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(SalesforceEndpointConfig.BATCH_ID, bi[0].getId());
        exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody());
    }

})
.to("salesforce:getQueryResult")
.process(new Processor() {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
    {
        InputStream is = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);
        CachedOutputStream cos = new CachedOutputStream(exchange);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(cos);
        boolean header = false;
        String line = null;
        com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter writer = new com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter(pw);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        writer.beginArray();
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!header)
            {
                header = true;
                continue;
            }
            String[] split = line.split(",");
            JsonObject account = new JsonObject();
            JsonObject headers = new JsonObject();
            JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
            account.add("headers", headers);
            headers.addProperty("category", "entity");
            headers.addProperty("type", "Account");
            account.add("data", data);

            data.addProperty("accountId", split[0].substring(1, split[0].length() - 1));
            data.addProperty("name", split[1].substring(1, split[1].length() - 1));
            data.addProperty("accountType", split[2].substring(1, split[2].length() - 1));
            gson.toJson(account, writer);
        }
        writer.endArray();
        writer.flush();
        exchange.getOut().setBody(cos.getInputStream());

    }

})
.to("stream:out");
```

As you can see, what I am doing here is bulk-importing data from SF and converting it into JSON and saving it into a file. I simplified things for the purposes of this question.

I know that for the real world scenario I will have to replace the "from timer" part of the route with a SEDA or a VM producer.

Any help is great appreciated.

Regards,
Oleg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I decided not to use Camel Salesforce connector for this, and it is a shame. Lack of documentation for the library and not so clear source code comments made me concerned that I may spend more time getting the library to work than actually implementing my project.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I want to start by questioning your assumption of the bulk api.

The bulk api may be more trouble than it's worth here.

You could use the rest api, and some clever looping to pull your records. How many records are we talking about here?

Additionally, you might consider a flat-file (csv) export and load, or even a jitterbit/dataloader situation and have your system load from the .csv produced by that.

Despite Camel's association with the Apache foundation I had to go lookup what it was / did. I like to think of myself as fairly typical, so that may, unfortunately, mean you'll have a hard time finding camel expertise here.

Comment: I am concerned about limitations using REST API. I also need to automatically import lots of data, can't be using export and load manually, although I did consider it. Also from what I understand export to CSV ends up using Bulk API...

Comment: The other issue, is that polling for batch status counts against API usage... and likewise, paginating using REST API counts against API usage as well...

Comment: yes, anyway you do it, you're gonna be facing api call limits.

Comment: how many Rows are we talking here? I can pull 15k in under 5 seconds with the rest api ...

Answer (score 0):

Will the awaitility utility help you to solve this!
https://code.google.com/p/awaitility

Answer (score 0):

I found out this solution below:

```
public Predicate stopLoopPredicate() {
    Predicate stopLoop = new Predicate() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
             return exchange.getIn().getBody() != null && !exchange.getIn().getHeader("stateBatch").toString().equals("COMPLETED");
        }
    };
    return stopLoop;
}

.......................

    .to("salesforce:createJob")
    .to("salesforce:createBatchQuery?sObjectQuery=select Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,MobilePhone from Contact")
    .to("salesforce:getBatch")
      
    .process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            BatchInfo batchInfo = exchange.getIn().getBody(BatchInfo.class);
            bi[0] = batchInfo;
            BatchStateEnum stateBatch = batchInfo.getState();
            exchange.getMessage().setHeader("stateBatch", stateBatch.toString());
            exchange.getMessage().setBody(batchInfo);
        }
    })

    .loopDoWhile(stopLoopPredicate())

    .to("salesforce:getBatch")

    .process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            BatchInfo batchInfo = exchange.getIn().getBody(BatchInfo.class);
            bi[0] = batchInfo;
            BatchStateEnum stateBatch = batchInfo.getState();
            exchange.getMessage().setHeader("stateBatch", stateBatch.toString());
            exchange.getMessage().setBody(batchInfo);
        }
    })

    .end()

......................
```